# javascript calling a member function from inside a member function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am fairly new to javascript, and converting some (very old) code to something a bit more modern, and refactoring, and I have ended up with something like this

```
var MyClass = function(parms} {/*stuff*/} 
MyClass.prototype = {
    this_func(p1, p2) { /* do this */ },
    that_func(args) { /* do that */ }
};
```

note I don't have the ES6 `class` keyword available, but I'd like to move to using that as soon as it becomes available to me.

The problem comes when I want to call `this_func` from inside `that_func` and I have managed to end up with this contortion

```
that_func(args) {
    //this.this_func(parm1, parm2) causes an error
    myClass.prototype.this_func.call(this, parm1, parm2);
}
```

Is there an easier way of doing this? And when I get full es6 will I just be able to use `this.this_func` ?

I've looked at the existing questions on this site and none of them really seem to cover what I'm doing (or at least not in a way I can map to my problem)

Clarification - the class is used like this

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.that_func('xxx');
```

and I get an error about `this_func` not being known (which I can't recall at the moment, due to being a long way from the code in question right now)

Comment: You should be able to use `this.this_func` right now. That's how it's supposed to work

Comment: However, I think you are declaring the prototype functions wrong. Could you show the actual code?

Comment: that's how it's worked since brendan was a boy

Comment: Show us how you *call* `that_func`, because if you (maybe) pass function references around, you lose the context of the object.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen - that's ES6 shorthand ... `{ x: function() {} }` == `{ x() {}}`

Comment: `note I don't have the ES6 class keyword available` - stop using internet exploder, or Opera mini

Comment: @JaromandaX when he mentioned that ES6 class keyword isn't available to him, I assumed the other features aren't available either.

Comment: yeah, I thought that was very strange too!!!

Comment: I agree with @BlazeSahlzen [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u9gjrseL/)

Comment: Seems like the OP went on holiday...

Comment: @JaromandaX I've got a good amount of pejorative names for IE, but 'exploder' is my personal favourite.

Comment: I don't have ES6 available, OK? Whilst I appreciate the pity, it's not helping to solve the issue.

Comment: What is your "environment" that doesn't have es6 class but does have the es6 shortcut function declaration syntax?

Comment: palemoon browser.

Comment: This page: http://es6-features.org/#GetterSetter suggests that that syntax is in es5m which is why I coded it like that

Comment: It is not ES5 getter/setter. It is ES6 shorthand method, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to current instance. If the class was properly instantiated with `new MyClass(...)`, prototype chain is set up automatically, this is the purpose of `prototype` object.

It should be

```
MyClass.prototype = {
    this_func(p1, p2) {...},
    that_func(args) {
        this.this_func(...);
    }
};
```

If you 'don't have the ES6 class keyword available', Babel can be used to transpile ES6 code to ES5. This is is what it is for.

Comment: yes, and that gives an error when I call this_func, which is why I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it after much adding of trace and logging. Today I discovered that if you have a function inside another function, the `this` value changes inside that inner function, so it doesn't belong to the 'class' instance in some sense (confusing when coming from a C++ background).